# How to checkmark a checkbox when testing with Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, integration-testing, laravel-5.3

I want to do application testing with Laravels built-in application testing framework. [Due to the documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/application-testing#interacting-with-your-application) you can check a checkbox with:

```
// HTML
<input name="accept-terms" type="checkbox">

// PHP
$this
    ->visit('/foo/bar')
    ->check('accept-terms')
```

Which works fine. However, sometimes I have a lot of checkboxes. Like:

```
// HTML
<input id="feature-1" name="features[]" type="checkbox" value="1">
<input id="feature-2" name="features[]" type="checkbox" value="2">
<input id="feature-3" name="features[]" type="checkbox" value="3">

// PHP
$this
    ->visit('/foo/bar')
    ->check('#feature-1')
```

I can't fetch them by name (as above), so I tried to fetch it by their ID. However, it seems like that's not supported, since I always get a `unreachable field` error.

Comment: This might work: `$this->visit('/foo/bar')->get('features[]')[0]->tick()`

Comment: Sure you mean `get`? `get` does trigger an HTTP GET request.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple instances of people asking the same questions. I can't seem to find how to do *exactly* what you are looking for. An alternative is to submit the value of the checkbox themselves instead of checking them.

```
$input = ['features' => [1,2]];

$this->visit('/foo/bar')
     ->submitForm('MyForm', $input);
```

Comment: This probably makes the most sense. As far as PHP tests go, we really only need to consider the input, not the state of the DOM. That said, there is the ```tick()``` method which should work.